# i want to send nested multiple arrays as json object in rest assured using java

Tags: rest-assured

i have api which i need to automate with restassured-java , body contains json as below , how should i proceed?

```
signal":{"numWindows" : 4,        "continuous": {"r" : "[199.0, 230.93, 230.75, 225.45, 219.66, 217.18, 213.54, 213.04, 210.88, 207.01, 207.965, 210.2075, 212.9175, 214.02, 213.1625, 212.49, 212.13, 212.21, 211.99, 211.99, 211.91, 211.99, 211.99, 212.13, 212.9, 213.04, 213.26, 213.91, 214.05, 214.34, 214.99, 215.0, 215.05, 215.29, 215.91, 215.99, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.95, 215.91, 215.91, 215.91, 215.75, 215.86, 215.86, 215.5, 215.3, 215.34, 215.46, 215.5, 215.29, 215.33, 215.29, 215.49, 215.29, 215.29, 215.29, 215.29, 215.25, 215.25, 215.25, 215.05, 215.01, 215.0, 215.04, 215.5, 215.96, 216.01, 216.05, 216.13, 216.66, 216.91, 216.87, 217.0, 216.96, 216.96, 216.71, 217.0, 217.0, 217.0, 216.75, 216.5, 216.25, 216.25, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 215.99, 215.99, 216.0, 215.87, 215.87, 215.67, 215.35, 215.13, 215.62, 215.7, 215.66, 215.66, 215.47, 215.5, 215.87, 215.9, 215.91, 215.95, 215.95, 215.95, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 216.0, 215.99, 215.99, 216.0, 216.0, 216.01, 216.01, 216.05, 216.01, 216.01, 216.05, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 215.99, 216.0, 216.0, 215.99, 215.99, 215.95, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 216.0, 216.0, 215.99, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.01, 216.01, 216.01, 216.0, 216.05, 216.01, 216.01, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 215.99, 215.95, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.95, 215.99, 215.99, 215.98, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.95, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.95, 215.87, 215.91, 215.91, 215.91, 215.91, 215.86, 215.86, 215.86, 215.86, 215.86, 215.86, 215.86, 215.86, 215.7, 215.86, 215.95, 215.96, 215.96, 216.01, 215.99, 216.0, 216.0, 216.01, 216.01, 216.01, 215.99, 215.91, 215.87, 215.7, 215.47, 215.5, 215.46, 215.46, 215.46, 215.34, 215.3, 215.26, 215.09, 215.42, 215.41, 215.38, 215.46, 215.46, 215.5, 215.5, 215.5, 215.58, 215.58, 215.54, 215.74, 215.75, 215.9, 215.91, 215.7, 215.54, 215.5, 215.49, 215.3, 215.29, 215.17, 215.13, 215.13, 215.09, 215.09, 215.09, 215.09, 215.09, 215.09, 215.1, 215.09, 215.1, 215.1, 215.09, 215.13, 215.26, 215.3, 215.3, 215.34, 215.46, 215.86, 215.66, 215.5, 215.5, 215.46, 215.22, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.0, 215.0, 215.0, 215.0, 215.0, 215.01, 215.0, 215.01, 215.01, 215.01, 215.01, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.01, 215.01, 215.0, 215.0, 214.96, 214.95, 214.99, 214.95, 214.95, 214.95, 214.95, 214.95, 214.91, 214.95, 214.95, 214.87, 214.91, 214.91, 
214.91, 214.95, 214.99, 214.99, 214.99, 214.99, 214.99, 215.0, 215.0, 214.99, 214.99, 214.99, 214.99, 214.99, 214.95, 214.9, 214.86, 214.86, 214.86, 214.86, 214.78, 214.82, 214.82, 214.82, 214.62, 214.7, 214.7, 214.66, 214.7, 214.7, 214.7, 214.87, 214.86, 214.86, 214.86, 214.86, 214.9, 214.82, 214.66, 214.5, 214.5, 214.29, 214.25, 214.09, 214.14, 214.09, 214.09, 214.1, 214.09, 214.09, 214.09, 214.09, 214.1, 214.26, 214.3, 214.45, 214.62, 214.78, 214.78, 214.62, 214.62, 214.62, 214.45, 214.29, 214.09, 214.01, 214.05, 214.01, 214.01, 214.0, 214.01, 214.01, 214.01, 214.01, 214.0, 214.01, 214.01, 214.01, 214.01, 214.01, 214.01, 214.05, 214.09, 214.05, 214.09, 214.05, 214.05, 214.05, 214.03, 213.99, 213.9, 213.9, 213.86, 213.86, 213.86, 213.86, 213.86, 213.82, 213.66, 213.82, 213.86, 213.9, 213.9, 213.9, 213.91, 213.95, 213.92, 214.0, 214.0, 214.0, 214.01, 214.0, 213.99, 213.99, 213.95, 213.86, 213.86, 213.66, 213.66, 213.66, 213.44, 213.47, 213.45, 213.45, 213.46, 213.5, 213.34, 213.5, 213.46, 213.5, 213.7, 213.7, 213.7, 213.86, 213.86, 213.95, 213.99, 213.95, 213.99, 213.98, 213.84, 213.84, 213.84, 213.62, 213.3, 213.1, 213.09, 213.05, 213.01, 213.25, 213.25, 213.2, 213.27, 213.26, 213.25, 213.25, 213.26, 213.3, 213.3, 213.3, 213.46, 213.46, 213.46, 213.62, 213.62, 213.66, 213.62, 213.46, 213.13, 213.09, 213.04, 213.0, 213.03, 212.94, 212.91, 212.9, 212.86, 212.86, 212.86, 212.86, 212.91, 212.87, 212.91, 212.94, 212.94, 212.98, 212.95, 213.04, 213.01, 213.05, 213.05, 213.05, 213.25, 213.05, 213.08, 213.06, 212.97, 212.94, 213.04, 214.05, 214.34, 214.96, 215.01, 215.09, 215.34, 215.75, 216.0, 216.0, 216.05, 216.05, 216.13, 216.29, 216.3, 216.3, 216.34, 216.66, 216.86, 216.91, 216.95, 216.91, 216.99, 216.95, 216.95, 216.95, 216.95, 216.99, 216.99, 216.87, 216.7, 216.78, 216.46, 216.46, 216.42, 216.26, 216.25, 216.42, 216.58, 216.25, 216.26, 216.46, 216.7, 216.54, 216.71, 216.71, 216.71, 216.66, 216.91, 216.91, 216.95, 216.91, 216.91, 216.82, 216.62, 216.615, 216.41,216.09, 216.09, 216.05, 216.05, 216.09, 216.08, 216.08, 216.05, 216.05, 216.05, 216.04, 216.05, 216.09, 216.09, 216.09, 216.09, 216.09, 216.09, 216.13, 216.13, 216.26, 216.17, 216.13, 216.09, 216.08, 216.04, 216.0, 216.01, 216.0, 215.95, 215.99, 215.91, 215.91, 215.95, 215.91, 215.95, 215.95, 215.95, 215.95, 215.99, 215.99, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 215.97, 215.96, 215.96, 215.96, 216.0, 216.0, 215.99, 215.95, 215.75, 215.75, 215.91, 215.9, 215.75, 215.74, 215.71, 215.71, 215.87, 215.91, 215.86, 215.91, 215.9, 215.91, 215.91, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.99, 215.95, 215.95, 215.9, 215.9, 215.9, 215.82, 215.7, 215.18, 215.18, 215.18, 215.17, 215.18, 215.33, 215.66, 215.5, 215.5, 215.66, 215.5, 215.66, 215.66, 215.66, 215.82, 215.87, 215.91, 215.91, 215.91, 215.75, 215.75, 215.55, 215.5, 215.18, 215.1, 215.13, 215.05, 215.13, 215.05, 215.09, 215.05, 215.05, 215.13, 215.09, 215.09, 215.13, 215.09, 215.3, 215.46, 215.3, 215.5, 215.7, 215.7, 215.74, 215.91, 215.74, 215.74, 215.7, 215.5, 215.3, 215.26, 215.1, 215.05, 215.05, 215.04, 215.05, 215.04, 215.01, 215.05, 215.05, 215.05, 215.09, 215.25, 215.42, 215.46, 215.3, 215.3, 215.46, 215.7, 215.74, 215.75, 215.86, 215.82, 215.78, 215.615, 215.58, 215.46, 215.25, 215.1, 215.09, 215.08, 215.04, 215.05, 215.0, 215.09, 215.09, 215.26, 215.26, 215.31, 215.38, 215.14, 215.34, 215.62, 215.66, 215.5, 215.66, 215.7, 215.9, 215.94, 215.9, 215.87, 215.7, 215.5, 215.45, 215.46, 215.3, 215.1, 215.09, 215.13, 215.05, 215.09, 215.09, 215.05, 215.05, 215.01, 215.09, 215.13, 215.14, 215.3]",
                         "g" : "[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.505, 3.91, 6.43, 11.29, 12.79, 14.98, 18.01, 18.965, 22.2075, 25.9175, 28.02, 28.6625, 29.49, 29.13, 29.21, 28.99, 28.99, 28.91, 28.99, 28.99, 29.13, 29.9, 30.04, 30.26, 30.91, 31.05, 31.34, 31.99, 32.0, 32.05, 32.29, 32.91, 32.99, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 32.99, 32.99, 32.99, 32.99, 32.95, 32.91, 32.91, 32.91, 32.75, 32.61, 32.61, 32.25, 32.05, 32.09, 32.21, 32.25, 32.04, 32.08, 32.04, 32.24, 32.04, 32.04, 32.04, 32.04, 32.0, 32.0, 32.0, 31.8, 31.76, 31.75, 31.79, 32.0, 31.96, 32.01, 32.05, 32.13, 32.66, 32.91, 32.87, 33.0, 32.96, 32.96, 33.21, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.25, 33.5, 33.75, 33.75, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 33.99, 33.99, 34.0, 33.87, 33.87, 33.67, 33.35, 33.13, 33.62, 33.7, 33.66, 33.66, 33.47, 33.5, 33.87, 33.9, 33.91, 33.95, 33.95, 33.95, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 34.0, 33.99, 33.99, 34.0, 34.0, 34.01, 34.01, 34.05, 34.01, 34.01, 34.05, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 33.99, 34.0, 34.0, 33.99, 33.99, 33.95, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 34.0, 34.0, 33.99, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.01, 34.01, 34.01, 34.0, 34.05, 34.01, 34.01, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 33.99, 33.95, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.95, 33.99, 33.99, 33.98, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.95, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.95, 33.87, 33.91, 33.91, 33.91, 33.91, 33.86, 33.86, 33.86, 33.86, 33.86, 33.86, 33.86, 33.86, 33.7, 33.86, 33.95, 33.96, 33.96, 34.01, 33.99, 34.0, 34.0, 34.01, 34.01, 34.01, 33.99, 33.91, 33.87, 33.7, 33.47, 33.5, 33.46, 33.46, 33.46, 33.34, 33.3, 33.26, 33.09, 33.42, 33.41, 33.38, 33.46, 33.46, 33.5, 33.5, 33.5, 33.58, 33.58, 33.54, 33.74, 33.75, 33.9, 33.91, 33.7, 33.54, 33.5, 33.49, 33.3, 33.29, 33.17, 33.13, 33.13, 33.09, 33.09, 33.09, 33.09, 33.09, 33.09, 33.1, 33.09, 33.1, 33.1, 33.09, 33.13, 33.26, 33.3, 33.3, 33.34, 33.46, 33.86, 33.66, 33.5, 33.5, 33.46, 33.22, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.01, 33.0, 33.01, 33.01, 33.01, 33.01, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.01, 33.01, 33.0, 33.0, 32.96, 32.95, 32.99, 32.95, 32.95, 32.95, 32.95, 32.95, 32.91, 32.95, 32.95, 32.87, 32.91, 32.91, 32.91, 32.95, 32.99, 32.99, 32.99, 32.99, 32.99, 33.0, 33.0, 32.99, 32.99, 32.99, 32.99, 32.99, 32.95, 32.9, 32.86, 32.86, 32.86, 32.86, 32.78, 32.82, 32.82, 32.82, 32.62, 32.7, 32.7, 32.66, 32.7, 32.7, 32.7, 32.87, 32.86, 32.86, 32.86, 32.86, 32.9, 32.82, 32.66, 32.5, 32.5, 32.29, 32.25, 32.09, 32.14, 32.09, 32.09, 32.1, 32.09, 32.09, 32.09, 32.09, 32.1, 32.26, 32.3, 32.45, 32.62, 32.78, 32.78, 32.62, 32.62, 32.62, 32.45, 32.29, 32.09, 32.01, 32.05, 32.01, 32.01, 32.0, 32.01, 32.01, 32.01, 32.01, 32.0, 32.01, 32.01, 32.01, 32.01, 32.01, 32.01, 32.05, 32.09, 32.05, 32.09, 32.05, 32.05, 32.05, 32.03, 31.99, 31.9, 31.9, 31.86, 31.86, 31.86, 31.86, 31.86, 31.82, 31.66, 31.82, 31.86, 31.9, 31.9, 31.9, 31.91, 31.95, 31.92, 32.0, 32.0, 32.0, 32.01, 32.0, 31.99, 31.99, 31.95, 31.86, 31.86, 31.66, 31.66, 31.66, 31.44, 31.47, 31.45, 31.45, 31.46, 31.5, 31.34, 31.5, 31.46, 31.5, 31.7, 31.7, 31.7, 31.86, 31.86, 31.95, 31.99, 31.95, 31.99, 31.98, 31.84, 31.84, 31.84, 31.62, 31.3, 31.1, 31.09, 31.05, 31.01, 31.25, 31.25, 31.2, 31.27, 31.26, 31.25, 31.25, 31.26, 31.3, 31.3, 31.3, 31.46, 31.46, 31.46, 31.62, 31.62, 31.66, 31.62, 31.46, 31.13, 31.09, 31.04, 31.0, 31.03, 30.94, 30.91, 30.9, 30.86, 30.86, 30.86, 30.86, 30.91, 30.87, 30.91, 30.94, 30.94, 30.98, 30.95, 31.04, 31.01, 31.05, 31.05, 31.05, 31.25, 31.05, 31.08, 31.06, 30.97, 30.94, 31.04, 32.05, 32.34, 32.96, 
33.01, 33.09, 33.34, 33.75, 34.0, 34.0, 34.05, 34.05, 34.13, 34.29, 34.3, 34.3, 34.34, 34.66, 34.86, 34.91, 34.95, 34.91, 34.99, 34.95, 34.95, 34.95, 34.95, 34.99, 34.99, 34.87, 34.7, 34.78, 34.46, 34.46, 34.17, 34.26, 34.25, 34.42, 34.58, 34.25, 34.26, 34.46, 34.7, 34.54, 34.71, 34.71, 34.71, 34.66, 34.91, 34.91, 34.95, 34.91, 34.91, 34.82, 34.62, 34.615,34.41, 34.09, 34.09, 34.05, 34.05, 34.09, 34.08, 34.08, 34.05, 34.05, 34.05, 34.04, 34.05, 34.09, 34.09, 34.09, 34.09, 34.09, 34.09, 34.13, 34.13, 34.26, 34.17, 34.13, 34.09, 34.08, 34.04, 34.0, 34.01, 34.0, 33.95, 33.99, 33.91, 33.91, 33.95, 33.91, 33.95, 33.95, 33.95, 33.95, 33.99, 33.99, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 33.97, 33.96, 33.96, 33.96, 34.0, 34.0, 33.99, 33.95, 33.75, 33.75, 33.91, 33.9, 33.75, 33.74, 33.71, 33.71, 33.87, 33.91, 33.86, 33.91, 33.9, 33.91, 33.91, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.99, 33.95, 33.95, 33.9, 33.9, 33.9, 33.82, 33.7, 33.18, 33.18, 33.18, 33.17, 33.18, 33.33, 33.66, 33.5, 33.5, 33.66, 33.5, 33.66, 33.66, 33.66, 33.82, 33.87, 33.91, 33.91, 33.91, 33.75, 33.75, 33.55, 33.5, 33.18, 33.1, 33.13, 33.05, 33.13, 33.05, 33.09, 33.05, 33.05, 33.13, 33.09, 33.09, 33.13, 33.09, 33.3, 33.46, 33.3, 33.5, 33.7, 33.7, 33.74, 33.91, 33.74, 33.74, 33.7, 33.5, 33.3, 33.26, 33.1, 33.05, 33.05, 33.04, 33.05, 33.04, 33.01, 33.05, 33.05, 33.05, 33.09, 33.25, 33.42, 33.46, 33.3, 33.3, 33.46, 33.7, 33.74, 33.75, 33.86, 33.82, 33.78, 33.615, 33.58, 33.46, 33.25, 33.1, 33.09, 33.08, 33.04, 33.05, 33.0, 33.09, 33.09, 32.76, 32.76, 32.81, 32.88, 33.14, 33.34, 33.62, 33.66, 33.5, 33.66, 33.7, 33.9, 33.94, 33.9, 33.87, 33.7, 33.5, 33.45, 33.46, 33.3, 33.1, 33.09, 33.13, 33.05, 33.09, 33.09, 33.05, 33.05, 33.01, 33.09, 33.13, 33.14, 33.3]",                        "b" : "[5.25, 87.43, 86.75, 79.45, 76.16, 71.93, 57.79, 54.19, 51.88, 48.01, 46.965, 47.2075, 49.4175, 51.02, 51.1625, 51.49, 51.13, 51.21, 50.99, 50.99, 50.91, 50.99, 50.99, 51.13, 51.9, 52.04, 52.26, 52.91, 53.05, 53.34, 53.99, 54.0, 54.05, 54.29, 54.91, 54.99, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 54.99, 54.99, 54.99, 54.99, 54.95, 54.91, 54.91, 54.91, 54.75, 55.11, 55.11, 54.75, 54.55, 54.59, 54.71, 54.75, 54.54, 54.58, 54.54, 54.74, 54.54, 54.54, 54.54, 54.54, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.3, 54.26, 54.25, 54.29, 55.0, 55.96, 56.01, 56.05, 56.13, 56.66, 56.91, 56.87, 57.0, 56.96, 56.96, 57.46, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 56.99, 56.99, 57.0, 56.87, 56.87, 56.67, 56.35, 56.13, 56.62, 56.7, 56.66, 56.66, 56.47, 56.5, 56.87, 56.9, 56.91, 56.95, 56.95, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.49, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.49, 57.49, 57.49, 57.49, 57.49, 57.49, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.0, 56.99, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 57.01, 57.01, 57.05, 57.01, 57.01, 57.05, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 56.99, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.01, 57.01, 57.01, 57.0, 57.05, 57.01, 57.01, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.98, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.95, 56.87, 56.91, 56.91, 56.91, 56.91, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.7, 56.86, 56.95, 56.96, 56.96, 57.01, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 57.01, 57.01, 57.01, 56.99, 56.91, 56.87, 56.7, 56.47, 56.5, 56.46, 56.46, 56.46, 56.34, 56.3, 56.26, 56.09, 56.42, 56.41, 56.38, 56.46, 56.46, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.58, 56.58, 56.54, 56.74, 56.75, 56.9, 56.91, 56.7, 56.54, 56.5, 56.49, 56.3, 56.29, 56.17, 56.13, 56.13, 
56.09, 56.09, 56.09, 56.09, 56.09, 56.09, 56.1, 56.09, 56.1, 56.1, 56.09, 56.13, 56.26, 56.3, 56.3, 56.34, 56.46, 56.86, 56.66, 56.5, 56.5, 56.46, 56.22, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.01, 56.0, 56.01, 56.01, 56.01, 56.01, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.01, 56.01, 56.0, 56.0, 55.96, 55.95, 55.99, 55.95, 55.95, 55.95, 55.95, 55.95, 55.91, 55.95, 55.95, 55.87, 55.91, 55.91, 55.66, 55.7, 55.74, 55.74, 55.74, 55.49, 55.49, 55.5, 55.5, 55.49, 55.49, 55.49, 55.49, 55.49, 55.45, 55.4, 55.36, 55.11, 55.11, 55.11, 55.03, 55.07, 55.07, 54.82, 54.62, 54.7, 54.7, 54.66, 54.7, 54.7, 54.7, 54.87, 54.86, 54.86, 54.86, 54.86, 54.9, 54.82, 54.66, 54.5, 54.5, 54.29, 54.25, 54.09, 54.14, 54.09, 54.09, 54.1, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.1, 54.26, 54.3, 54.45, 54.62, 54.78, 54.78, 54.62, 54.62, 54.62, 54.45, 54.29, 54.09, 54.01, 54.05, 54.01, 54.01, 54.0, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.0, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.05, 54.09, 54.05, 54.09, 54.05, 54.05, 54.05, 54.03, 53.99, 53.9, 53.9, 53.86, 53.86, 53.86, 53.86, 53.86, 53.82, 53.66, 53.82, 53.86, 53.9, 53.9, 53.9, 53.91, 53.95, 53.92, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.01, 54.0, 53.99, 53.99, 53.95, 53.86, 53.86, 53.66, 53.66, 53.66, 53.44, 53.47, 53.45, 53.45, 53.46, 53.5, 53.34, 53.5, 53.46, 53.5, 53.7, 53.7, 53.7, 53.86, 53.86, 53.95, 53.99, 53.95, 53.99, 53.98, 53.84, 53.84, 53.84, 53.62, 53.3, 53.1, 53.09, 53.05, 53.01, 53.25, 53.25, 53.2, 53.27, 53.26, 53.25, 53.25, 53.26, 53.3, 53.3, 53.3, 53.46, 53.46, 53.46, 53.62, 53.62, 53.66, 53.62, 53.46, 53.13, 53.09, 53.04, 53.0, 53.03, 52.94, 52.91, 52.9, 52.86, 52.86, 52.86, 52.86, 52.91, 52.87, 52.91, 52.94, 52.94, 52.98, 52.95, 53.04, 53.01, 53.05, 53.05, 53.05, 53.25, 53.05, 53.08, 53.06, 52.97, 52.94, 53.54, 55.05, 55.34, 55.96, 56.01, 56.09, 56.84, 57.25, 58.0, 58.0, 58.55, 58.55, 59.13, 59.29, 59.3, 59.3, 59.34, 59.66, 59.86, 59.91, 59.95, 59.91, 59.99, 59.95, 59.95, 59.95, 59.95, 59.99, 59.99, 59.87, 59.7, 59.78, 59.46, 59.46, 59.92, 59.26, 59.25, 59.42, 59.58, 59.25, 59.26, 59.46, 59.7, 59.54, 59.71, 59.71, 59.71, 59.66, 59.91, 59.91, 59.95, 59.91, 59.91, 59.82, 59.62, 59.615, 59.41, 59.09, 59.09, 59.05, 59.05, 59.09, 59.08, 59.08, 59.05,59.05, 59.05, 59.04, 59.05, 59.09, 59.09, 59.09, 59.09, 59.09, 59.09, 59.13, 59.13, 59.26, 59.17, 59.13, 59.09, 59.08, 58.54, 58.5, 58.51, 58.5, 58.45, 58.49, 58.41, 58.41, 58.45, 58.91, 58.45, 58.45, 58.45, 58.45, 58.49, 58.99, 59.0, 59.0, 58.5, 59.0, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.47, 58.46, 58.46, 58.46, 58.5, 58.5, 58.49, 58.45, 58.25, 58.25, 58.41, 58.4, 58.25, 57.74, 57.71, 57.21, 57.37, 57.41, 57.36, 57.41, 58.4, 57.91, 57.41, 58.49, 57.99, 58.49, 57.99, 58.49, 57.49, 57.95, 57.95, 57.9, 58.4, 57.9, 57.82, 57.2, 56.68, 56.18, 56.18, 56.17, 56.18, 56.33, 56.66, 56.5, 56.5, 57.16, 56.5, 56.66, 56.66, 56.66, 56.82, 56.87, 56.91, 56.91, 56.91, 56.75, 56.75, 56.55, 56.5, 56.18, 56.1, 56.13, 56.05, 56.13, 56.05, 56.09, 56.05, 56.05, 56.13, 56.09, 56.09, 56.13, 56.09, 56.3, 56.46, 56.3, 56.5, 56.7, 56.7, 56.74, 56.91, 56.74, 56.74, 56.7, 56.5, 56.3, 56.26, 56.1, 56.05, 56.05, 56.04, 56.05, 56.04, 55.76, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.09, 56.25, 56.42, 56.46, 56.3, 56.3, 56.46, 56.7, 56.74, 57.25, 57.36, 57.32, 57.28, 57.115, 56.58, 56.46, 56.25, 56.1, 56.09, 56.08, 56.04, 56.05, 56.0, 56.09, 56.09, 56.01, 56.01, 56.06, 56.13, 56.14, 56.34, 56.62, 56.66, 56.5, 56.66, 56.7, 56.9, 56.94, 56.9, 56.87, 56.7, 56.5, 56.45, 56.46, 56.3, 56.1, 56.09, 56.13, 56.05, 56.09, 56.09, 56.05, 56.05, 56.01, 56.09, 56.13, 56.14, 56.3]"                         },
             "window":{"b" : ";[5.25, 87.43, 86.75, 79.45, 76.16, 71.93, 57.79, 54.19, 51.88, 48.01, 46.965, 47.2075, 49.4175, 51.02, 51.1625, 51.49, 51.13, 51.21, 50.99, 50.99, 50.91, 50.99, 50.99, 51.13, 51.9, 52.04, 52.26, 52.91, 53.05, 53.34, 53.99, 54.0, 54.05, 54.29, 54.91, 54.99, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 54.99, 54.99, 54.99, 54.99, 54.95, 54.91, 54.91, 54.91, 54.75, 55.11, 55.11, 54.75, 54.55, 54.59, 54.71, 54.75, 54.54, 54.58, 54.54, 54.74, 54.54, 54.54, 54.54, 54.54, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.3, 54.26, 54.25, 54.29, 55.0, 55.96, 56.01, 56.05, 56.13, 56.66, 56.91, 56.87, 57.0, 56.96, 56.96, 57.46, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 56.99, 56.99, 57.0, 56.87, 56.87, 56.67, 56.35, 56.13, 56.62, 56.7, 56.66, 56.66, 56.47, 56.5, 56.87, 56.9, 56.91, 56.95, 56.95, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.49, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.49, 57.49, 57.49, 57.49, 57.49, 57.49, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.0, 56.99];[56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 57.01, 57.01, 57.05, 57.01, 57.01, 57.05, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 56.99, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.01, 57.01, 57.01, 57.0, 57.05, 57.01, 57.01, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.98, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.95, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 56.99, 56.99, 56.99, 56.95, 56.87, 56.91, 56.91, 56.91, 56.91, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.86, 56.7, 56.86, 56.95, 56.96, 56.96, 57.01, 56.99, 57.0, 57.0, 57.01, 57.01, 57.01, 56.99, 56.91, 56.87, 56.7, 56.47, 56.5, 56.46, 56.46, 56.46, 56.34, 56.3, 56.26, 56.09, 56.42, 56.41, 56.38, 56.46, 56.46, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.58, 56.58, 56.54, 56.74, 56.75, 56.9, 56.91, 56.7, 56.54, 56.5, 56.49, 56.3, 56.29, 56.17, 56.13, 56.13, 56.09, 56.09, 56.09, 56.09, 56.09, 56.09, 56.1, 56.09, 56.1, 56.1, 56.09, 56.13, 56.26, 56.3];[56.3, 56.34, 56.46, 56.86, 56.66, 56.5, 56.5, 56.46, 56.22, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.01, 56.0, 56.01, 56.01, 56.01, 56.01, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.05, 56.01, 56.01, 56.0, 56.0, 55.96, 55.95, 55.99, 55.95, 55.95, 55.95, 55.95, 55.95, 55.91, 55.95, 55.95, 55.87, 55.91, 55.91, 55.66, 55.7, 55.74, 55.74, 55.74, 55.49, 55.49, 55.5, 55.5, 55.49, 55.49, 55.49, 55.49, 55.49, 55.45, 55.4, 55.36, 55.11, 55.11, 55.11, 55.03, 55.07, 55.07, 54.82, 54.62, 54.7, 54.7, 54.66, 54.7, 54.7, 54.7, 54.87, 54.86, 54.86, 54.86, 54.86, 54.9, 54.82, 54.66, 54.5, 54.5, 54.29, 54.25, 54.09, 54.14, 54.09, 54.09, 54.1, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.1, 54.26, 54.3, 54.45, 54.62, 54.78, 54.78, 54.62, 54.62, 54.62, 54.45, 54.29, 54.09, 54.01, 54.05, 54.01, 54.01, 54.0, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.0, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.01, 54.05, 54.09, 54.05, 54.09, 54.05, 54.05, 54.05, 54.03, 53.99, 53.9, 53.9, 53.86, 53.86, 53.86, 53.86, 53.86, 53.82];[53.66, 53.82, 53.86, 53.9, 53.9, 53.9, 53.91, 53.95, 53.92, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.01, 54.0, 53.99, 53.99, 53.95, 53.86, 53.86, 53.66, 53.66, 53.66, 53.44, 53.47, 53.45, 53.45, 53.46, 53.5, 53.34, 53.5, 53.46, 53.5, 53.7, 53.7, 53.7, 53.86, 53.86, 53.95, 53.99, 53.95, 53.99, 53.98, 53.84, 53.84, 53.84, 53.62, 53.3, 53.1, 53.09, 53.05, 53.01, 53.25, 53.25, 53.2, 53.27, 53.26, 53.25, 53.25, 53.26, 53.3, 53.3, 53.3, 53.46, 53.46, 53.46, 53.62, 53.62, 53.66, 53.62, 53.46, 53.13, 53.09, 53.04, 53.0, 53.03, 52.94, 52.91, 52.9, 52.86, 52.86, 52.86, 52.86, 52.91, 52.87, 52.91, 52.94, 52.94, 52.98, 52.95, 53.04, 53.01, 53.05, 53.05, 53.05, 53.25, 53.05, 53.08, 
53.06, 52.97, 52.94, 53.54, 55.05, 55.34, 55.96, 56.01, 56.09, 56.84, 57.25, 58.0, 58.0, 58.55, 58.55, 59.13, 59.29, 59.3, 59.3, 59.34, 59.66, 59.86, 59.91, 59.95, 59.91, 59.99, 59.95, 59.95, 59.95, 59.95, 59.99, 59.99, 59.87, 59.7, 59.78, 59.46, 59.46, 59.92, 59.26, 59.25, 59.42, 59.58, 59.25, 59.26, 59.46, 59.7, 59.54, 59.71, 59.71, 59.71, 59.66, 59.91, 59.91];[59.95, 59.91, 59.91, 59.82, 59.62, 59.615, 59.41, 59.09, 59.09, 59.05, 59.05, 59.09, 59.08, 59.08, 59.05, 59.05, 59.05, 59.04, 59.05, 59.09, 59.09, 59.09, 59.09, 59.09, 59.09, 59.13, 59.13, 59.26, 59.17, 59.13, 59.09, 59.08, 58.54, 58.5, 58.51, 58.5, 58.45, 58.49, 58.41, 58.41, 58.45, 58.91, 58.45, 58.45, 58.45, 58.45, 58.49, 58.99, 59.0, 59.0, 58.5, 59.0, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.47, 58.46, 58.46, 58.46, 58.5, 58.5, 58.49, 58.45, 58.25, 58.25, 58.41, 58.4, 58.25, 57.74, 57.71, 57.21, 57.37, 57.41, 57.36, 57.41, 58.4, 57.91, 57.41, 58.49, 57.99, 58.49, 57.99, 58.49, 57.49, 57.95, 57.95, 57.9, 58.4, 57.9, 57.82, 57.2, 56.68, 56.18, 56.18, 56.17, 56.18, 56.33, 56.66, 56.5, 56.5, 57.16, 56.5, 56.66, 56.66, 56.66, 56.82, 56.87, 56.91, 56.91, 56.91, 56.75, 56.75, 56.55, 56.5, 56.18, 56.1, 56.13, 56.05, 56.13, 56.05, 56.09, 56.05, 56.05, 56.13, 56.09, 56.09, 56.13, 56.09, 56.3, 56.46, 56.3, 56.5, 56.7, 56.7, 56.74, 56.91, 56.74, 56.74, 56.7, 56.5, 56.3, 56.26, 56.1, 56.05, 56.05, 56.04, 56.05, 56.04, 55.76, 56.05]",                       }            },    "frameStartPoint" : 154,    "fps" : 45.9652706843718,    "startWindow" : 2,    "endWindow" : 6,    "model_id" : "Vivo 1907",        "uid" : "76df8bb3-c594-40ba-ad66-8eb53add1014",          "predicted_spo2" : 99.16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can save your large data in files and use POJO as usual.

For example:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import lombok.Data;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Test3 {

    @Data
    static class RequestBody {
        private Signal signal;
        private int frameStartPoint;
    }

    @Data
    static class Signal {
        private int numWindow;
        private Continuous continuous;
        private Window window;
    }

    @Data
    static class Continuous {
        private String r;
        private String g;
        private String b;
    }

    @Data
    static class Window {
        private String b;
    }

    @Test
    void name() throws IOException {
        String r = Files.readString(Path.of("src/test/resources/r.text"));
        String g = Files.readString(Path.of("src/test/resources/g.text"));
        String b = Files.readString(Path.of("src/test/resources/b.text"));

        Window window = new Window();
        window.setB(b);

        Continuous continuous = new Continuous();
        continuous.setR(r);
        continuous.setG(g);
        continuous.setB(b);

        Signal signal = new Signal();
        signal.setNumWindow(2);
        signal.setContinuous(continuous);
        signal.setWindow(window);

        RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody();
        requestBody.setFrameStartPoint(154);
        requestBody.setSignal(signal);

        RestAssured.given().log().body()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(requestBody)
                .post("https://postman-echo.com/post");
    }
}
```

Result (I just save a small data in files to make result readable)

```
Body:
{
    "signal": {
        "numWindow": 2,
        "continuous": {
            "r": "[199.0, 230.93, 215.14, 215.3]",
            "g": "[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.505, 33.3]",
            "b": "[5.25, 87.43, 56.3]"
        },
        "window": {
            "b": "[5.25, 87.43, 56.3]"
        }
    },
    "frameStartPoint": 154
}
```